# How to perform Boolean Query using SolrJ?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I need to add some complex rules on a *facetQuery* using *SolrJ*

I don't wanna directly add the whole **Solr** query string, but add the fq texts dynamically like we do for other facet query like `query.addDateRangeFacet` or `query.addFacetField` and apply AND/OR/NOT operator on the added facet.

Is that possible using `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery` and not `org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery` ?

Comment: what did you try so far? which Solr version you're using?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do with the facet?

Comment: I am accommodating an advanced search feature where user will select on which fields he/she wants to search and the corresponding keyword, hse should be able to define the operator between two categories/fields as well. There should not have any limitation in the number of fields.

Comment: @Mysterion I am using 4.9 here, solrj version: 5.5.2

Comment: could give an example, that will help to understand your needs? let's say you have 3 facet fields A B C with different terms, could you show what you want to achieve in terms of final solr query?